# Jekyll - Change the Markdown blockquote HTML output

Tags: html, css, markdown, jekyll

I'm learning Jekyll, and I have this basic file, which is prefaced by YAML frontmatter:

```markdown
---
layout: 'post'
---

> Test Quote
```

I've successfully managed to link my `CSS` stylesheet to the top wrapper `page.html` file. But there's a problem in that when Jekyll turns this `Markdown` into `HTML`, it turns this quote into:

```html
<blockquote>
  <p>Test Quote</p>
</blockquote>
```

Yet I need it to generate into:

```html
<blockquote>
  <div class="quote-line-container">
    <div class="quote-line"></div>
    <div class="quote-mark">“</div>
    <div class="quote-line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="quote-container">
    <p class="quote">Test Quote</p>
  </div>
</blockquote>
```

I've tried searching every variation of the words "Jekyll change Markdown HTML output" I can and no relevant results appear for my case.

How could I do this, and change the Jekyll output? Or is there a better way to generate something like this, using `CSS` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not possible to do**. Jekyll uses Kramdown as its Markdown engine and the customization of the process is pretty limited (as one would expect). You can see all the options [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/).

For this reason, your alternatives are:

1. Making your own Markdown engine for Jekyll (which is clearly overkill).
2. Making some preprocessing script to call before Jekyll only to perform that substitution. If you have a lot to translate, it is your best alternative.
3. Writing **your blockquotes directly as you want** them generated. Jekyll will leave your HTML code intact during the Markdown translation, so the result will be the one you want.

Comment: I think Option 3 is the best workaround. Thanks for your answer.